# RegEx-Tel Number Allowing spam dashes to be inputted

Tags: php, regex

I have no idea why it is allowing multiple dashes to be inputted,been at this for ages now.

```
if (empty($_POST['Tel'])||strlen(trim($_POST['Tel']))==0)
{$TelErr="<br>*Missing tel<br>";}
else if (strlen($_POST['Tel'])<11)
{$TelErr="<br>*Tel Number too short<br>";}
else if (strlen($_POST['Tel'])>12)
{$TelErr="<br>*Tel Number too long<br>";}
else if (preg_match("/^[0-9+]$/", $_POST['Tel']))
{$TelErr="<br>*Please use numbers only<br>";}
```

Comment: Should this be tagged `php`?

Comment: You're only matching a single number there. You probably want a `+` after `[0-9]`

Comment: Could you give us some more information? What are you getting now? What should you be getting?

Comment: Ive tried that already bud, prevents the phone number but still allows the dashes

Comment: Vincent, I want to input a tel number, just numbers, would like to allow a single space or a single dash, but not allow multiple dashes

Comment: Can you show more code how you're doing it.

Comment: The usual way to do this is to discard punctuation and normalize to just numbers.  Then the user can input however many spaces and dashes they want, in adherence with or violation of applicable national / regional standards as they wish.

Comment: anubhava, I've added more code to show what im working with, Im fairly new to all this so Im guessing it's something simple

Comment: `preg_match("/^[0-9+]$/", $_POST['Tel'])` should be: `preg_match("/^[0-9]+$/", $_POST['Tel'])` i.e. `+` outside character class.

Comment: Thanks Anubhava but that doesn't fix my problem as I can still input multiple dashes and submit that as an entry, I want to prevent this

Comment: Just remove `else ` before `if (preg_match...` to make sure this is always executed.

Comment: Still doesnt make a difference, im able to enter ------------ and submit it

Comment: There is no way it accepts `-----`, provide output of `var_dump($_POST['Tel']);`

Comment: says string(11) "-----------"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try somethin like this:

```
preg_match("/^(\d+-?)+\d+$/", $_POST['Tel'])
```

Using '?' to match the nearest dash.

Here an exmaple:

```
1 <?php
2 $texts = array('123-456', '123--456', '-----------');
3 foreach ($texts as $text) {
4     if (preg_match("/^(\d+-?)+\d+$/", $text, $match)){
5         echo "$text is valid\n";
6     } else {
7         echo "$text is not valid\n";
8     }
9 }
10 ?>
```

Output:

```
123-456 is valid
123--456 is not valid
----------- is not valid
```

Comment: Thanks for the help luis but doesnt seem to prevent spam dashes

Comment: Could you give me an example, I've tried it with multiple dashes strings (123--456) and it doesn't match.

Comment: Should I input '-----------' it satisfies the match, I want to prevent this

Comment: That case doesn't match, at least in my php, I've updated the response with the complete example and the output.

Comment: You're welcome, anyway it seems you are showing the "Please use numbers only" to the numbers that match the expression, it's right?

Comment: Ah...well spotted, I did mention Im a complete amateur,right?lol. Ive marked your response as the fix, thanks dude